# AWS DMS "Unsupported or commented out DDL" when CDC is enabled on MySQL source

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am running an AWS Data Migration (DMS) job from RDS MySQL to a Redshift cluster, I have enabled detailed cloudwatch logs to capture the errors that are happening. I'm getting errors when insert and update statements are ran on the source MySQL DB `Unsupported or commented out DDL`, but the statements don't have a commented DDL. Below are some sample errors:

```
2020-11-30T10:53:22:726844 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]T: >>> Unsupported or commented out DDL: 'INSERT INTO `table_name_1` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `logs`, `ip`, `log_posts`, `action`, `before_or_after`, `user_agent`) VALUES ('1234', 'blah_blah', 'inspection/from_website', '0.0.0.0', '[]', 'View', '', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; RMX2151) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Mobile Safari/537.36')' (mysql_endpoint_capture.c:1717)

2020-11-30T10:48:49:892445 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]T: >>> Unsupported or commented out DDL: 'UPDATE `table_name_2` SET `timestamp` = 1606733299 WHERE `id` = 'lkajdfoaiiuo00wueorinalkdfj'' (mysql_endpoint_capture.c:1717)
```

Both of these tables are partitioned tables on the MySQL source DB. I searched AWS DMS trouble shooting documentation, but I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting AWS Support, they said that the source MySQL RDS must be restarted after changing the parameters for making the logs binary & row, even though they're dynamic parameters. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Full load had succeeded completely. But the CDC records were not getting written to target. On checking the logs, saw the same statements for all the records.
Restarting the RDS instance after changing the configurations(binlog_format, binlog_checksum, binlog_row_image) did solve the issue.